# How to send ether from a user to another?

Tags: solidity

This should be really easy but I can't seem to find the way to do it, thanks to the *great* documentation. I'm thinking I'm missing something big.

I have a function that buys ownership of something. I want to remove `amount` ether to `msg.sender` (user **a**) and give them to `owner` (user **b**) (minus fees).

Can I do it directly? Do I have to first let **a** send ether to the contract and then send **b** the same amount, or is there a function to transfer directly?

I assume `owner.transfer(amount)` (or `.send(amount)`) sends ether from the contract to the owner, but then how do I get ether from **a**?

I'm using [Solidity by Example](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.3.1/solidity-by-example.html#blind-auction) as a model, but in the Blind Auction example I can't seem to find what function actually sends ether from the bidder to the contract.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just take somebody's ether, so yes, they need to send it to the contract first, but this can all be done in a single contract call. E.g.

```
// "payable" means ether can be sent to this function
function buyIt() public payable {
    // msg.value is how much ether was sent
    require(msg.value == price);

    // send the ether to "owner"
    owner.transfer(msg.value);

    // msg.sender is the new "owner"
    owner = msg.sender;
}
```

When calling this function, the caller must attach `price` ether. This means setting the "value" field of the transaction.

I think this blog post will help: https://programtheblockchain.com/posts/2017/12/15/writing-a-contract-that-handles-ether/.

**EDIT**

You linked to a very old version of the Solidity documentation, before `payable` was required to allow ether to be sent. [The current version](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/solidity-by-example.html#blind-auction) shows a `payable` `bid` function. That's where ether is transferred to the contract.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that you could change the version on readthedocs! With this function, the price is chosen by the buyer, right? If the `price` is fixed, do I have to check that he sent more than `price` and then refund all the exceeding ether, or can something handle that automatically?

Comment: I just made up `price`. I assumed a fixed price. The code I shared requires that the caller send exactly the right amount. If you want to allow overpayment and refund the excess, you could do `require(msg.value >= price); if (msg.value > price) { msg.sender.transfer(msg.value - price); }`.

Comment: Oh my bad, I missed the part with `require`. It's crystal clear now! :)

Answer (score -1):

How about web3 sendTransaction method? it has "to" option.

https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethsendtransaction

Comment: It needs to be inside the contract, I can't do this just at JavaScript level.

Comment: I got it! exactly! We need to go through contract